# Need to edit a file using GDrive which is stored in my application

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have my own application where user uploads a file. Now whenever he want to edit this file, my application will try to open this file using google docs.
This is a web-application in java. How to do it?

I didn't see a sample for same in net.

Comment: Drive uses Docs to open documents by default. What do you want to use instead? If this is Java related, could you share the code where you edit the files from your app?

Comment: I want to edit files like word/powerpoint/Excel using GDrive online, but file is stored in my server. This is just like Box or Drop Box is doing.

Comment: I just started collecting information to do this, so coding is not started yet.

Answer (score 0):

Drive equivalent of Dropbox would be "Back up and Sync" which you would need to install in your server, but it's only available for Windows and Mac. 
Supposing your server is Linux, the only thing I think of is uploading manually the files with a script, and downloading them to the server after the user finishes editing.

For more information, you can check the Drive Quickstart [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java). 
Regarding the GDrive online, you can change the default apps using the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata) too. In conclusion, unless your server runs on Windows, I think it’s a complex thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

My development team tried to solve similar problem. However, from what I see it can not be solved, and here is why:

- To edit document it must be converted to Google format. Even though
  it is possible to automatically convert document using Google API, the document formatting will break
  significantly. Constant round-trip conversions and formatting breaks
  make such solution unusable (at least in our case).
- Alternatively, you can convert and store documents in your DMS in Google format (Json), so the conversion and formatting does not happen when you edit them. But
  from what we see there is no way to upload a Json Google Docs
  document back to Google. Even though there are Google Drive API for
  uploading documents it either does not support Google Docs Json
  format or it is simply broken. See this post for more details: [Writing a Google Docs document in Google format (Json) does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877211/writing-a-google-docs-document-in-google-format-json-does-not-work)